# F#: always "unexpected 'when' keyword"

Tags: syntax, f#, visual-studio-2010

The VS2010 Beta 2 F# compiler always complains about my usage of the when keyword, even when using copy-pasted code which is supposed to work, such as either of [these snippets](http://diditwith.net/2008/04/24/YetAnotherProjectEulerSeriesYAPES.aspx). For instance, this is the error I get when trying to execute a very trivial expression:

"Error FS0010: Unexpected keyword 'when' in expression. Expected '->' or other token.  "

```
[for i in 1..50 when i < 10 -> i]  
---------------^^^^
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want

```
[for i in 1..50 do
    if i < 10 then
        yield i]
```

The 'short' syntax with 'when' was removed a while back.  See

http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2008/08/29/detailed-release-notes-for-the-f-september-2008-ctp-release.aspx

and look for "compact sequence expressions" in that document.

Answer (score 8):

You should use the yield keyword now. Like that:

```
[for i in 1 .. 50 do if i < 10 then yield i]
```

Comment: According to the F# keyword reference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233249(VS.100).aspx), when is used only in pattern matches and generic type constraints.  Possibly a change to the language since the article you cited came out?

Comment: I just can advise you to be a little careful when using snippets from old blog posts (minor language changes could have occurred).